# bootstrap label and control inline - max width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to arrange an input field so that it spans the column its in, minus the width of its label. i.e. on a large screen, the label is about 150px wide and the field takes up the rest. On a medium screen the same thing happens: label is about 150 wide, field takes up the remaining, thus:

```
+---+--------------------------------------------+
| n |                                            |
| a | Label: [_field___________________________] | 
| v |                                            |
|   |                                            |
+---+--------------------------------------------+

+---+--------------------------+
| n |                          |
| a | Label: [_field_________] | 
| v |                          |
|   |                          |
+---+--------------------------+
```

My form so far:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">{{ 'RequestTimeOff.SearchEmployee' | translate }}</label>
        <input name="searchQuery"
                [(ngModel)]="query"
                class="form-control">
    </div>
</form>
```

I can't seem to find the right combination to do it.

Comment: For the type of design you're trying to achieve here you may benefit from `.form-horizontal` over `.form-inline` - see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Comment: Yes. I tried that. Updated opening post.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.form-horizontal` you need to specify a `.col` for the `<label>` element as well as a `.col` wrapper for the `<input>` as per the Bootstrap documentation (v3) for Horizontal Forms

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Label</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input name="your-input" placeholder="Your Input" class="form-control">
  </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Note: The snippet might not render the label on the left here, depending on the size of your screen resolution.  Expand the snippet to the full screen to view the correct implementation.